# Extract data without geometries from `sf` objects like in `sp@data`

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

Probably a very basic question but I found nothing in the documentation of Simple Features R package.

I'm looking for the native `sf` function to extract on the fly all the columns of an sf object without the geometries. Just like `SP@data` with `sp` objects.

The following function does the job but I would prefer to use a native function :

```
st_data <- function(SF) { SF[, colnames(SF) != attr(SF, "sf_column"), drop = TRUE]}
```

A typical use is when I want to merge two sf dataset by attribute (`merge` does not work with two `sf` objects) : `merge(SF1, st_data(SF2))`.

In that case it would be impractical to use `st_geometry(SF2) <- NULL` because it does not work "on the fly" and I don't want to permanently drop the geometry column and `SF2[,1:5,drop=T]` is impractical too because I have to look into the object to see where the geometry column is.

Using : `sf_0.5-4` - `R 3.4.1`

Comment: what is a sf object?  from which library it comes?

Comment: @and-bri `library(sf)`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but they have a [migrating from sp to sf wiki](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/wiki/migrating) which may be useful

Comment: @SymbolixAU : Thanks for the link to the wiki. Very useful ! I have updated it with the accepted answer (and comment in it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the `st_geometry<-` function and set the geometry to be `NULL`.

```
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc_df <- `st_geometry<-`(nc, NULL)

class(nc_df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

As you can see, `nc_df` is a dataframe now, so I think you can do the following for your example.

```
merge(SF1, `st_geometry<-`(SF2, NULL))
```

#### Update

As Gilles pointed out, another function, `st_set_geometry`, can also achieve the same task. It is probably a better choice since using `st_set_geometry` does not need the use of "``" and "<-" to enclose the `st_geometry` function.

Comment: Great ! Exactly what I needed. I did not thougth about the functional form of `st_geometry<-`. But thanks to you I also just discovered another function that I overlooked that works very similarly : `st_set_geometry(SF, NULL)`. Could you please add it to your reply ?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for sharing the use of `st_set_geometry`. I have added this information to the post.

Comment: The normal (R) way of using replacement functions (those ending in `<-`) is `st_geometry(nc) <- NULL`, which is understood as "replace the geometry of `nc` with `NULL`, i.e., remove it".

Comment: @EdzerPebesma Thanks for your comments, Prof. Pebesma! I agree that `st_geometry(nc) <- NULL` should be interpreted as "replacement", not "removal".

Comment: Also possible with `st_drop_geometry(nc)`